# How to write a program that solves discount + price

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

A software company sells a package that retails for $99. Quantity discounts are applied if the number of packages ordered is:

```
Quantity              Discount
10 - 19                20%
20 - 49                30%
50 - 99                40%
100 or more            50%
```

Create an application SoftwareSales that prompts the user to enter the number of software packages ordered, calculates the cost of the purchase, and displays the result.
The application can be console or GUI based.

How should I approach this?

I know I need something like this in there?

```
if(score < 10) {
    discount = 0.0
} else if(score < 20){
    discount = 0.1
}
// other cases go here
```

Anyone want to at least give me the frame/skeleton for a program like this?

Comment: Those tags aren't really what you're asking. What language are you trying to write this in?

Comment: As you say, the assignment has three parts: input, calculation and display. Which part(s) do you need help with?

Comment: I have no idea where you got the "0.1" from, but for quantities less than 20 the stated "discount" is 20%, which isn't "0.1". But even if it were, it's wrong. The best way to figure out the answer is not to write the code first, but rather by describing the algorithm. I'll give you a hint. When 15 packages are ordered, the discount is not 20% on all 15, but only on the 10th through the 15th package. So, once you have the number of packages, you have to figure out how many packages get what level of discount. This is not complicated, just write out the algorithm in plain language, then code it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think that's how it works—at least he didn't phrase the problem that way.

Comment: @royhowie of course it has to work this way. Otherwise it makes no sense. 9 packages for $99 costs $891. 10 packages cost $990 full price. If you give a 20% discount on all of them, you'll be paying $792, so, under your proposal, buying 10 packages is cheaper than buying 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;    

int userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter no. of packages: "));
double cost = 99;
double finalCost;

if(userInput>=10 && userInput<20){
    finalCost= cost - ((cost/100)*20)
} else if(userInput>=20 && userInput<50){
    finalCost= cost - ((cost/100)*30)
} else if( etc.)
```

That's the basic variables you'll need and all you need to do is fill in the conditions of each discount. You won't learn much if I gave you all the code, hope it helps!

Comment: How would I set the discount? And what would adding other conditions look like?

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Comment: how would I start this program though? It won't work if I start it like that.

Comment: Indeed, you need to finish the if conditions. It's a simple case of copy pasting the two there and changing a handful of numbers to suit your needs. You'll also need to include the import.

Answer (score 0):

You must use something like this:

```
if(score >= 10 && <= 19)
  {
      discount = 0.20;
  }
else if(score >= 20 && <= 49)
{
    discount = 0.30;
}
 And so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table:

```
private static class Discount {
    private final int fromQuantity;
    private final double percent;

    public Discount(int fromQuantity, double percent) {
        this.fromQuantity = fromQuantity;
        this.percent = percent;
    }
}

public static final Discount[] DISCOUNT_TABLE = {
    new Discount(10, 20),
    new Discount(20, 30),
    new Discount(50, 40),
    new Discount(100, 50)
};
```

To get the discount percentage for a quantity:

```
public static double discountForQuantity(int quantity) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        --i;
    } while (i >= 0 && DISCOUNT_TABLE[i].fromQuantity > quantity);
    return i < 0 ? 0 : DISCOUNT_TABLE[i].percent;
}
```

To calculate the price of some quantity of the product:

```
public static double priceForQuantity(int quantity, double basePrice) {
    return quantity*basePrice*(1-(discountForQuantity(quantity)/100));
}
```